# how to check my new IP and location using TOR

Tags: ip, tor

I am running TOR on Windows 7. I would like to know my IP address after changing my identity. Right now the only option is to open a webpage with a service that shows my IP address.

Is there any way to find my IP without doing this? I tried to go through options or logs, but with no success.

P.S why do I need this. I need to connect to a service which works only for specific countries, so I am just waiting till my IP will be the IP of needed country. If someone know a better way to achieve this - welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure Tor to [prefer certain exit nodes](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit), including by country code. For example, if you want your exit node to be in the UK, France or Germany:

```
ExitNodes {gb},{fr},{de}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. Country codes should be in small letters and in this format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 ?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://check.torproject.org/ . There is no other way than to use an external service. This is because Tor circuits are built dynamically (and rebuilt every few minutes, or when you hit the New Identity button).